# Ошибка в цикле while, Python 3.10

Tags: python

Дано натуральное число. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет: сумму его цифр; количество цифр в нем; произведение его цифр; среднее арифметическое его цифр; его первую цифру; сумму его первой и последней цифры.

```
n = int(input())
total = 0 # сумма цифр
counter = 0 #количество цифр в числе
proizvedenie = 0
sred = 0
fist_last = 0
last_digital = n % 10
digital_2 = (n % 100) // 10
digital_3 = (n % 1000) // 100
first_digital = n // 1000
total += (last_digital+digital_2+digital_3+first_digital)    
print(total)

while n > 0 : # считаем количество цифр
    if n >=99:
        counter += 2
    elif 100 < n >=999:
        counter += 3
    elif 1000< n >=9999:
        counter += 3
    n = int(input())
print(counter)

proizvedenie += (last_digital*digital_2*digital_3*first_digital)
print(proizvedenie)

sred = total/counter
print(sred)

if n <= 99:
    fist_last = last_digital + digital_2
print(fist_last)
if 100 < n <= 999:
    fist_last = last_digital + digital_3
print(fist_last)
if 1000 < n <= 9999:
    fist_last = last_digital + first_digital
print(fist_last)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 21, in <module>
    n = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Сама ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 21, in <module>
    n = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Какая задача? Что вы вводите на input? Условия внутри while какие-то безумные

Comment: В цикле я считал количество цифр, для 3-х случаев. В int(input()) вводится число.

Comment: ОК, внесите условие задачи в начало вопроса.

Comment: Это где? Вообще не понимаю куда писать

Comment: Кнопка "Править" для редактирования вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число вводится один раз.

```
n = int(input())
last = n % 10
dsum = 0
dprod = 1
d = 0
cnt = 0 if n else 1
while n:
    d = n%10
    dsum += d
    dprod *= d
    cnt += 1
    n //= 10
print(dsum, cnt, dprod, dsum/cnt, last+d)
```

Comment: ОО понял, спасибо!